# Parsing pipe-delimited text file in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I have the following text file:

```
CUI|SDUI|HpoStr|MedGenStr|MedGenStr_SAB|STY|
CN000002|HP:0000001|All|All|HPO|Finding|
CN000003|HP:0000002|Abnormality of body height|Abnormality of body height|GTR|Finding|
CN000004|HP:0000003|Multicystic kidney dysplasia|Multicystic kidney dysplasia|GTR|Finding|
CN000006|HP:0000005|Mode of inheritance|Mode of inheritance|HPO|Finding|
C0443147|HP:0000006|Autosomal dominant inheritance|Autosomal dominant inheritance|GTR|Intellectual Product|
C0441748|HP:0000007|Autosomal recessive inheritance|Autosomal recessive inheritance|HPO|Intellectual Product|
CN000009|HP:0000008|Abnormality of female internal genitalia|Abnormality of female internal genitalia|GTR|Finding|
```

I want to parse this using Perl. This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (FILE, 'filename.txt');

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    ($CUI, $SDUI, $HpoStr, $MedGenStr, $MedGenStr_SAB, $STY) = split("\t");
    print "CUI: $CUI\n";
    print "SDUI: $SDUI\n";
    print "HpoStr: $HpoStr\n";
    print "MedGenStr: $MedGenStr\n";
    print "MedGenStr_SAB: $MedGenStr_SAB\n";
    print "STY: $STY\n";
    print "---------\n";
}

close (FILE);
exit;
```

I do get an output when I run it with the nano editor, but when I use a command like `perl filename.pl` I have many errors. I want to know whether my code is wrong or if there is a better way to structure my code.

-1 down vote accept

the case in the above code i have the input as a separate .txt file
#

CUI|SDUI|HpoStr|MedGenStr|MedGenStr_SAB|STY|

CN000002|HP:0000001|All|All|HPO|Finding| CN000003|HP:0000002|Abnormality of body height|Abnormality of body height|GTR|Fi nding| CN000004|HP:0000003|Multicystic kidney dysplasia|Multicystic kidney dysplasia|GT R|Finding| CN000006|HP:0000005|Mode of inheritance|Mode of inheritance|HPO|Finding| C0443147|HP:0000006|Autosomal dominant inheritance|Autosomal dominant inheritanc e|GTR|Intellectual Product| C0441748|HP:0000007|Autosomal recessive inheritance|Autosomal recessive inherita nce|HPO|Intellectual Product| CN000009|HP:0000008|Abnormality of female internal genitalia|Abnormality of fema le internal genitalia|GTR|Finding|
#

if i wanted to use as file input option how do i go about it?? as the size of the file is as big as 1gb.

and these are the header files i have to associate entries with these headers

Comment: Does that input file have any line breaks in it? Can you make sure it's formatted above like it looks on the computer where your code will run?

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are delimited by pipes (`|`), not tabs, so that's what you need to split on:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split(/\|/, $_);
    dd(\@fields);   
}

__DATA__
CUI|SDUI|HpoStr|MedGenStr|MedGenStr_SAB|STY|
CN000002|HP:0000001|All|All|HPO|Finding|
CN000003|HP:0000002|Abnormality of body height|Abnormality of body height|GTR|Finding|
CN000004|HP:0000003|Multicystic kidney dysplasia|Multicystic kidney dysplasia|GTR|Finding|
CN000006|HP:0000005|Mode of inheritance|Mode of inheritance|HPO|Finding|
C0443147|HP:0000006|Autosomal dominant inheritance|Autosomal dominant inheritance|GTR|Intellectual Product|
C0441748|HP:0000007|Autosomal recessive inheritance|Autosomal recessive inheritance|HPO|Intellectual Product|
CN000009|HP:0000008|Abnormality of female internal genitalia|Abnormality of female internal genitalia|GTR|Finding|
```

Output:

```
["CUI", "SDUI", "HpoStr", "MedGenStr", "MedGenStr_SAB", "STY"]
["CN000002", "HP:0000001", "All", "All", "HPO", "Finding"]
[
  "CN000003",
  "HP:0000002",
  "Abnormality of body height",
  "Abnormality of body height",
  "GTR",
  "Finding",
]
[
  "CN000004",
  "HP:0000003",
  "Multicystic kidney dysplasia",
  "Multicystic kidney dysplasia",
  "GTR",
  "Finding",
]
...
```

If you want to supply a file to read, just change `while (<DATA>)` to `while (<>)` and run the script like so: `perl script.pl input.txt`.

If you need access to the fields by name, you want a hash:

```
my @headers;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;  
    my @fields = split(/\|/, $_);

    if ($. == 1) {
        @headers = @fields;
        next;
    }

    my %data;
    @data{@headers} = @fields;
    dd(\%data); 
}
```

Output:

```
{
  CUI => "CN000002",
  HpoStr => "All",
  MedGenStr => "All",
  MedGenStr_SAB => "HPO",
  SDUI => "HP:0000001",
  STY => "Finding",
}
{
  CUI => "CN000003",
  HpoStr => "Abnormality of body height",
  MedGenStr => "Abnormality of body height",
  MedGenStr_SAB => "GTR",
  SDUI => "HP:0000002",
  STY => "Finding",
}
...
```

However, it looks like you're quickly approaching the point where using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) would be better than trying to do this by hand.

Comment: the case in the above code i have the input as a .txt file

Comment: @MosesV See my edits. However, it sounds like you might benefit from learning some Perl on your own. Check out the free books on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).